# How can I calculate Manhattan Distance using eigen library?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two vectors like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv())
{
.........
Vector3f center(0.4,0.1,0.3) ;
Vector3f point(0.1,0.2,0.7);
.......
}
```

How can I calculate Manhattan distance using eigen library? I am using VS2010.

Comment: Just by getting the magnitude between the two points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't hard as long as you know what Manhattan distance is (though I haven't seen the term used for 3D vectors before) - just have a look in the Eigen API doc for the relevant functions, you'll then find that the following works:

```
Vector3f center(0.4,0.1,0.3) ;
Vector3f point(0.1,0.2,0.7);
Vector3f diff = center - point;
float manh_dist = diff.cwiseAbs().sum();
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to observe that the Manhattan distance correspond to the L1 norm which can be obtained using the generic lpNorm method with :

```
manh_dist = (center-point).lpNorm<1>();
```

See this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a1f78d41c2ab7389e3df08384371188bf) for reference.

Comment: +1. I actually like this solution better than mine, but you should make a small correction to actually answer the question: Manhattan distance is `L_1`, not `L_infinity`.